# REST endpoints with Sails.js scaffolding

Tags: node.js, rest, express, sails.js, endpoint

I am new to node and new to sails. So this question may be pretty stupid, but I have used the "sails generate prospects" command to generate a REST api. I can access that api by visiting /api/v1/prospects (i set up the prefix).

I used chrome's postman extension to POST the following json array to that api, and it worked perfectly:

```
{
            "contactInfo" : {
                "firstName" : "john",
                "lastName" : "Stamos",
                "company" : "Full House",
                "title" : "Owner", 
                "phone" : "(352) 555-5555",
                "email" : "ken@contact.com",
                "website" : "http://fullhouse.com",
                "facebookUrl" : "http://facebook.com/fullhouse",
                "twitterUrl" : "http://twitter.com/fullhouse",
                "linkedInUrl" : "http://linkedin.com/fullhouse",
                "backgroundInfo" : "Ken and I first got together when Cynthia needed a web designer!",
                "firstContact" : "2014-07-09T12:00:00Z"
            },
            "address" : {
                "address" : "1234 Somewhere Street",
                "address2" : "Suite 1",
                "city" : "Ocala",
                "state" : "FL",
                "zipcode" : "35675"
            },
            "files" : [
                {
                    "filename" : "2345456324-23445745.jpg",
                    "folder" : "some folders name",
                    "insDate" : "2014-07-09T12:00:00Z"
                },
                {
                    "filename" : "2345332423-3453565462.jpg",
                    "folder" : "some folders name",
                    "insDate" : "2014-07-09T12:00:00Z"
                }
            ],
            "notes" : [
                {
                    "note" : "She emailed me friday about a new project",
                    "teamMemberId" : 0,
                    "insDate" : "2014-07-09T12:00:00Z"
                },
                {
                    "note" : "Just talked to her about a proposal.",
                    "teamMemberId" : 0,
                    "insDate" : "2014-07-13T12:00:00Z"
                }
            ],
            "access" : [],
            "blockAccess" : [1],
            "ownerId" : 0
        }
```

Here's my question... I was using firebase earlier, and while I know that Firebase is probably a hell of a complicated program and they worked months to get it to work, I love how they have REST endpoints set up within a record. Is this possible out of the box with sails.js?

By that i mean, assuming i imported this same exact json array into firebase, i could query the endpoint:

api/v1/prospects/1/address and I would get back:

```
{
                    "address" : "1234 Somewhere Street",
                    "address2" : "Suite 1",
                    "city" : "Ocala",
                    "state" : "FL",
                    "zipcode" : "35675"
                }
```

or if I queried api/v1/prospects/1/files, I would get back:

```
[
                    {
                        "filename" : "2345456324-23445745.jpg",
                        "folder" : "some folders name",
                        "insDate" : "2014-07-09T12:00:00Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "filename" : "2345332423-3453565462.jpg",
                        "folder" : "some folders name",
                        "insDate" : "2014-07-09T12:00:00Z"
                    }
                ]
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how I could put together this kind of an API with sails.js or express.js? I want to avoid using firebase for my api, but its looking really tempting unless I can get something like this working. Any tutorials, videos, resources etc where exactly this API scheme are created would be wonderful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I didn't know whether this was possible or not, but I've tried and I got what you expected, so to make the short answer:

YES! you can do it and it works perfectly (at least in sails 0.10)

Comment: Are you serious? How are you doing that? When I do command: $sails generate prospects, it creates an api but it doesn't allow me to go INTO the api endpoints like that. How are you set up. I'd desperately love to know this

Comment: I actually did nothing, just "sails generate user" which has a collection of "passports" inside and I was able to do what you mention: /user/1/passports returns the list of passports of user 1 only. Unlessssss, it may be because I've explicitly defined the relationship among the two models (user and passport). Did you actually tried api/v1/prospects/1/address to see what comes out?

Comment: yeah it doesn't work like that for me. How did you define the relationship between the two models?

Comment: @DanielWhite here is the way how u can set up relations between two models in sails.js/waterline ORM https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/associations.md